# Using T1 RJ48X extender to extend RJ45 from cable modem. Possible?

Tags: networking, wiring

In our building, the demarc is on the complete opposite side from the network closet. So, the T1 is extended from the demarc with a CAT5E cable that runs across the building to the network closet and terminates at a RJ48X jack. From the RJ48X there is a thin, flat, network(? not labeled) cable that is run to the T1 modem/router.

We're switching to Comcast. Comcast installed the modem at the demarc. So, now I have to run from the modem all the way across the building with CAT5E. My question is, can I use the extender that is currently running from the T1 demarc to the RJ48X jack in the network closet to extend the cable modem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why you couldn't. Just snip it off and put on an end or a jack of your own.

Comment: Agreed. Just make sure that both ends are terminated identically.

Comment: And make sure the two transmit wires are on a twisted pair and the two receive wires on a twisted pair. Wiring 1-1, 2-2, 3-3, and so on typically *won't* do this.